# How to set “Negotiate Seal” in NTLMSSP_AUTH?

Tags: ntlm

not sure if this is right stackexchange site to ask this, but here it goes.

I have 2 servers (win 2003 and 2012) trying to do NTLM authentication with a UNIX box (with apache web server) with the same windows domain account. win 2003 server works perfectly but win 2012 one keep giving "Unauthorized" error.

I used wireshark trying to capture what are the differences and it comes down to "Negotiate Seal" and "Negotiate Sign". The bad server has those flags as "Not set". How can I make them to "Set"?

Thanks!

[image: wireshark screen cap]